# Python Selenium: Click on a radio button

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I was wondering how I can click on the button on this page using Python Selenium.

Here is the webpage:

https://hk.news.yahoo.com/poll/f83b2360-b41c-11e9-8d6b-b77be6568e98

The source code for the button is:

```
<label class="option Cur(p) Ov(h) D(b) Pos(r) Bxsh($BorderLikeBoxShadow) Bdc($borderGray) Px(15px) Py(23px)" data-reactid="43">
 <div class="Pos(r) D(tb)" data-reactid="44">
  <div class="D(tbc) Ta(c) Va(m)" data-reactid="45"><input type="radio" value="o0" class="D(n) check" name="option" data-reactid="46"><img class="Trsdu(.3s) Op(0.7) Fil($opacityMsOld) Mend(15px) W(26px) H(26px)" src="https://s.yimg.com/ji/news/ybrain/unselect@1x.png" alt="" data-reactid="47"></div>
  <div class="D(tbc) Va(m) Lh(1.5) C($c-fuji-grey-i) LineClamp(1) Fz(16px)" data-reactid="48">支持</div>
 </div>
</label>
```

I tried a script like below but it didn't work.

```py
import os
import glob
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')

link_url="https://hk.news.yahoo.com/poll/f83b2360-b41c-11e9-8d6b-b77be6568e98"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.get(link_url)

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='radio']")[0].click()
```

Any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WebdriverWait and javaScript Executor to click on the element using below xpath.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"(//label[contains(@class,'option Cur(p) Ov(h) D(b) Pos(r)')]//div[contains(@class,'D(tbc) Va(m)')])[1]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
```

OR

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"(//label[contains(@class,'option Cur(p) Ov(h) D(b) Pos(r)')]//img)[1]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
```

You need to import followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```